# Cant find Ubuntu after installation

Tags: edubuntu

How can I install Ubuntu along with windows7 with a DVD? I installed it on another drive but it doesn't show up in the startup menu...

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu and the Ubuntu loader on an external drive?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu and its boot loader on an external (or secondary) drive, you need to go into the BIOS settings to then boot from that drive, that's all!  **;-)**

If that's not what you wanted, [have a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).